# Is there a way to "wait" for "Azure Data Factory" Execution task to complete before executing next steps of Azure Logic Apps

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps, azure-data-factory

Trying to Load some Excel data using ADF pipeline via Logic Apps. However when triggering through Logic Apps, the task triggers and then moves to the next step immediately. Looking for a solution where the next step waits for a "Execute Data factory Pipeline" to execute completely before proceeding.

Adding an image for clarity.

-Thanks

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For this requirement, I provide a sample of my logic app below for your reference:

**1.** Add a "Create a pipeline run" action and initialize a variable named `status`(set its value as "**InProgerss**").

[image]

**2.** Then add a "[Until](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-control-flow-loops#until-loop)" action, set the break condition as `status` is equal to "**Succeeded**". Add a "**Get a pipeline run**" action and set the variable `status` as the value of `Status` comes from "**Get a pipeline run**" in the "**Until**" action. Shown as below screenshot:

[image]

**3.** After that, run your logic app. The steps will run after the "Until" action(also after your pipeline complete).

**By the way:**

You can also do it in Data Factory, you can delete the data after completion. Please refer to this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-azure-blob-storage#mapping-data-flow-properties).

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the good solution. File movement was confined to Logic apps in my solution, hence wanted to keep the solution clean by not using ADF for housekeeping activity.